# Как конвертировать список из str в тип int если сроки имеют пробелы

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

Здравствуйте. Имеется список (list), состоящий из строк (str). В начале, в середине и в конце этих строк есть пробелы, к тому же строка представлена в Unicode. Пример: `u' 21\xa0698 '`, `u' 23\xa0696 '` и т.д. Как мне конвертировать эти значения в Int? Я пробовал использовать функцию `map`, но ничего не получилось. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте [forloop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) и метод [encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html). Пробелы можно удали через `replace(' ', '')` или лучше стразу в Unicode при помощи `strip()`.

Comment: Функция `strip()` помогла, но надо было использовать `extract_first()` а я использовал `extract` и получал ошибку что `list` не имеет метода `strip()`. А с `extract_first()` все заработало. Оформи пожалуйста комментарий как ответ, я его приму. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [forloop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) и метод [encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html). Пробелы можно удали через `replace(' ', '')` или лучше стразу в Unicode при помощи `strip()`.